# Modifying variables that are passed by reference in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

I was watching a JavaScript talk, and the tutor said that if we pass a property of an object in a function it will actually change the real value, because we will be passing the variable by reference. Here is the slide:
[image]

but when I tried to practice the concept, that wasn't the case. Here is my code:

```
var obj = {val: 5};
function changeVal(x) {
 x = x+5;
 return x;
}
console.log(obj.val) // 5
console.log(changeVal(obj.val)) // 10
console.log(obj.val) // 5
```

I was expecting obj.val to change to 10. 
**Please tell me what's wrong here, and correct me if I am wrong. Thanks**

Comment: Read your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13104500/812519 there are plenty of answers and comments on this topic

Comment: but you're not passing an object...

Comment: Look into `call by value`, `call by reference` and `call by sharing`. Javascript uses the first (for primitives) and the last (for objects) evaluation strategy. Especially notice the difference between `by reference` and `by sharing` when reassigning a passed object.

Comment: Like Java, Javascript has PASS-BY-VALUE ONLY. Period. There is no pass-by-reference in JavaScript. You can pass primitives, by value, and you can pass references (pointers to objects), by value. "Objects" are not values in JavaScript and cannot be "passed".

Answer (score 1):

You are passing not the **object**, but the **primitive type**. So when you pass the `val` of the `obj`, it is a number and is a primitive type.It copies the **val** and passes the **copy** to the object.

If you pass like this, it will work

```
var obj = {val: 5};

function changeVal( param ) {
 param.val = param.val  + 5;
 return param.val ;
}
console.log(obj.val) // 5
console.log(changeVal(obj)) // 10
console.log(obj.val) // 10
```

Comment: the example would be a bit more clear if you name the parameter something different

Comment: @aw04 Agree with you

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually passing an object, just passing the value of property(val).
If you will pass **obj** in changeVal(), then it will actually change the value of the property of passed object.

For that you need to do like:

```
var obj = {val: 5};
function changeVal(x) 
{
    x = x+5;
    return x;
}
console.log(obj.val); // 5
changeVal(obj); // Need to pass object instead of value of the property's value
console.log(obj.val);  // 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Primitive types (string, integer, boolean, etc...) are immutable, which means if you change one of the values inside a function, the callee (scope which calls your function) will not see the change.

```
function doSomething(a) {
    a = a + 1;
}
var value = 2;
console.log(value); // result: 2
doSomething(value);
console.log(value); // result: 2
```

Pass-by-reference only works for objects. Like this:

```
function doSomething(obj) {
    obj.attribute = obj.attribute + 1;
}
var myObject = {attribute: 2};
console.log(myObject.attribute); // result: 2
doSomething(myObject);
console.log(myObject.attribute); // result: 3
```

More reading about Javascript types:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Answer (score 0):

Say for instance you have an Iphone . Now lets say a manufacturing company calls you and asks to borrow your Iphone for a reference just so they can design an Iphone that is similar and sell it to customers . Your original Iphone still exists and is never gone , but every now and then the factory needs to use it for a reference  , think of your function as the factory that just make a copy of `obj`.

```
//Original data

var obj = {val: 5};
```

Once your function returns something , it technically becomes a value

**Example :**

```
return 3; is a value of 3
```

so

```
function changeVal(x) {
 x = x+5;
 return x;
}
```

is a new value of x which in this case would be x + 5;

**x is a copy** of whatever you pass into the function .

Hope this helps.